# $t(n+1)=(t(n))^2, t(1)=2,$ what is $t(n)$

Tags: functions

I do not believe there is a function that satisfies these requirements, but I would like to know wether there is any function of arrangement of functions&numbers that would satisfies these requirements. Please give me your steps for how you got your answer.

Comment: If you see something wrong with this question please edit and if you require peer viewing please leave a note in the comments, or give me something to improve in the comments, thank you.

Comment: $t(n)=2^{2^{n-1}}$

Comment: @StinkingBishop please put that as an answer along with your steps.

Comment: I would leave the steps to you - once you know the formula you can easily check that it is valid for every $n$. How to *get* that formula - I suppose you try $t(2)=4=2^2=2^{2^1}, t(3)=16=2^4=2^{2^2}, t(4)=256=2^8=2^{2^3}$ etc. and figure out the rule.

Comment: Note that if $y(n)=\log_2(t(n))$, by taking $\log_2$ on the recurrence of $t(n)$ you see that $y(n)$ satisfies a homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coeffients $y(n+1)=2y(n)$, with initial condition $y(1)=1$.

Comment: ( to add to what @MoonLightSyzygy has said, there is an algorithm for solving those - look up this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a closed form, then $t(n) = 2^{2^{n-1}}$ for $n \geq 1.$

Edit: here's how you can come up with this formula. Suppose $t(n)= 2^{c^{n-1}}$ for some nonzero constant $c$ (we include $n-1$ since $t(1) = 2$). Then $t(n+1) = (t(n))^2 \Rightarrow 2^{c^n} = 2^{2c^{n-1}}\Rightarrow c^{n-1}(c-2)=0\Rightarrow c = 2.$

Comment: Can you please tell me your steps for how you got this answer

Comment: you can see this easily by listing the first few values of $t(n).$

Comment: got it, but how would you come up with this formula without a lot of work or knowing the answer beforehand. Can you give me an algebraic proof please. I understand it is correct, I just would like to know how to solve these types of problems in the future

Comment: I edited my post. For these relations, the closed form is usually exponential.